# How to deserialize an object with type info outside himself

Tags: json, deserialization, discriminated-union

I have a `Parent` type with one of its fields  is a `Discriminated Union` (`JsonSubTypes`).In my example below i keep the `Discriminant` (id) inside my child  field.
What i want to know is : is it possible to have the `discriminant` outside my `child` object and directly in the parent ?

**What works**

```
public class Parent{
    Child childField{get;set;}
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubTypes),CHILDTYPE)]
[JsonSubTypes.KnownSubTypes(typeof(Child1),CTYPE.Child1)]
[JsonSubTypes.KnownSubTypes(typeof(Child2),CTYPE.Child2)]
public abstract class Child{

    public enum Discriminator{
        Child1=0,
        Child2=1
    }

    private const string CHILDTYPE="childType";

    [JsonProperty(CHILDTYPE)]
    public abstract  Discriminator Kind{get;} //i want this moved to parent

}
public class Child1:Child{
    public int Value{get;set;}
    public override Kind=>Discriminator.Child1;
}
public class Child2:Child{
    public bool Value{get;set;}
    public override Kind=>Discriminator.Child2;
}
```

**Usage**

```
List<Parent>parents=new List<Parent>{new Child1{Value=3},new Child2{Value=True}};
var str=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parents);
List<Parent>parents=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Parent>(str);
```

**What i want**

```
 public class Parent{

        private const string CHILDTYPE="childType";

        public enum Discriminator{
         Child1=0,
         Child2=1
        }


        public abstract Discriminator Kind{get;} 

        Child childField{get;set;}
    }

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubTypes),CHILDTYPE)]
[JsonSubTypes.KnownSubTypes(typeof(Child1),CTYPE.Child1)]
[JsonSubTypes.KnownSubTypes(typeof(Child2),CTYPE.Child2)]
public abstract class Child
{

}
```

As you can see what i want is to **move** my `Kind` field from the `Child` and into the `Parent`.Can i somehow accomplish this? I want to keep everything the same , just instead of a `Json` like this:

```
{
    childField:{ Kind:3}
}
```

I need to accomodate for a json like this:

```
 {
    Kind:3
    childField:{}
}
```

Can i accomplish this ? Can i somehow decorate the parent to know to deserialize one of its fields based on another ?